# How to analyze Dataflow task programmatically?

Tags: c#, ssis

I am working in a tool (C#.Net) to analyze SSIS packages.
Here i am using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100`(class in dts.interop) class to iterate through Dataflow task(MainPipe). Please find the code below.

```
//Cast the Executable as a data flow
MainPipe pipe = (MainPipe)taskHost.InnerObject;
foreach (IDTSComponentMetaData100 comp in pipe.ComponentMetaDataCollection)
{
//Here i need
//1. Source details
//2. Destination details

}
```

Is it possible to type cast each `IDTSComponentMetaData100` object to some objects of dataflow components like XMLSource, OLEDB Destination etc? If it is possible, how will I be able to identify source, destination etc?

If it is not possible, kindly provide some tips to achieve this.

Comment: Check this article out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/api-sample-oledb-source-and-oledb-destination.aspx

Comment: Thanks praveen. This is how we can create a package dynamically but i need to analyze package. Below code will create a ne instance of IDTSComponentMetaData100 as OleDbDestination.    IDTSComponentMetaData100 destComponent =  pipeline.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
destComponent.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbDestination";
destComponent.ValidateExternalMetadata = true;
But I need to extract OleDbDestination by loop through the data flow. Please help...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there is no particularly useful way to cast an `IDTSComponentMetaData100` to "objects of dataflow components", in large part because there are **no** "objects of dataflow components". Behind the scenes, SSIS is a **COM**-driven application, particularly for the stock components, rather than a native .NET application. This is part of why creating SSIS dataflows programatically is so painful. (See [Adding Data Flow Components Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135932.aspx)
 in MSDN for a slightly more detailed discussion.)

That said, the `IDTSComponentMetaData100` interface does expose an `ObjectType` property, which is an [DTSObjectType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.dtsobjecttype.aspx) enum. Sources in a dataflow will have an `ObjectType` of `OT_SOURCEADAPTER`, destinations `OT_DESTINATIONADAPTER` and transformations `OT_TRANSFORM`.

Alternatively, you can investigate saving the package as a .dtsx file and parsing the resulting XML itself.

Comment: Thank you very much @Edmund Schweppe... So the only way to extract dataflow component is by parsion the resulting xml of the package...??

Comment: Since I don't know what precisely you mean by "extract dataflow component", I'm afraid I can't answer that question.

Comment: Mainly i want to record the source and destination of the data flow. For eg: if there is XML Source and OLEDB Destination, i need XSD Schema location, OLDB Destination connection etc...Thanks @Edmund

Answer (score 0):

Building on Edmunds answer above, You can test for OT_SOURCEADAPTER and OT_DESTINATION object types and then iterate over the custom properties and any linked connection(s) via the RuntimeConnectionCollection.  This will allow you to retrieve any custom property values or the associated connection(s) and any of the connection properties, such as connection name.
Psuedo code below to display custom properties and get source connection name, assumes you already have opened the package and have a reference to a MainPipe.

```
Mainpipe df; 
Package pkg;

foreach (IDTSComponentMetaData100 comp in df.ComponentMetaDataCollection)
{
  if ((comp.ObjectType & DTSObjectType.OT_SOURCEADAPTER ) == DTSObjectType.OT_SOURCEADAPTER )
  {

    foreach (IDTSCustomProperty100 cp in comp.CustomPropertyCollection)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}",cp.Name,cp.Value));
    }

    if (comp.RuntimeConnectionCollection.Count > 0)
    {
      IDTSRuntimeConnection100 rtconn = comp.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0];
      if (pkg.Connections.Contains(rtconn.ConnectionManagerID))
      {
        var conn = Package.Connections[rtconn.ConnectionManagerID];
        // Get the connection name
        varconnName = conn.Name;
      }
   }
 }
```

Example of retrieving a MainPipes connections taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtsruntimeconnection100.connectionmanager.aspx)